# How to create bashrc script for anonymous upload service file.io?

Tags: linux, file, service, upload, command

I am trying to create a script for my .bashrc that works for the anonymous file upload service file.io...

Here is what I have been working with but this one is for transfer.sh's service:

```
  # anonymous file uploading to transfer.sh via command line ($ upload file.any)
  upload() { if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then echo -e "No arguments specified. Usage:\necho transfer /tmp/test.md\ncat /tmp/test.md | transfer test.md"; return 1; fi 
  tmpfile=$( mktemp -t transferXXX ); if tty -s; then basefile=$(basename "$1" | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]/-/g'); curl --progress-bar --upload-file "$1" "https://transfer.sh/$basefile" >> $tmpfile; else curl --progress-bar --upload-file "-" "https://transfer.sh/$1" >> $tmpfile ; fi; cat $tmpfile; rm -f $tmpfile; }
```

which works wonderfully! but the code below which came from file.io's website is not helping me one bit. I feel I have tried everything but I am not the best at coding so far...

```
  curl -F "file=test.txt" https://file.io
  {"success":true,"key":"2ojE41","link":"https://file.io/2ojE41","expiry":"14 days"}
```

I have tried many different things, the first one being: (any many different variations as well)

```
  upload2 () {
    curl -F "file=$1" https://file.io
  {"success":true,"key":"2ojE41","link":"https://file.io/2ojE41","expiry":"14 days"}
  }
```

Can anyone help me to learn?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
upload2(){
    curl -F "file=@$1" https://file.io
}
```

Then you can use `upload2 Testfile`
and get the response:
`{"success":true,"key":"d8Lobo","link":"https://file.io/d8Lobo","expiry":"14 days"}`

Comment: Wow thank you very much! I really appreciate it! :) Hey do you know how I would change the expiration date? Possibly to forever? Thanks again Manuel!

Comment: change it to:
    `curl -F "file=@$1" https://file.io/?expires=999y`
and it expires after 999 years